# using Java to download file

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to download a file from this url, but the code hang at getInputStream();
I type this url in the browser. the url is accessible
http://filehost.blob.core.windows.net/firmware/version.txt

What is the cause of it ?

```
URL url = new URL("http://filehost.blob.core.windows.net/firmware/version.txt");
HttpURLConnection  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();  //hang at this line

int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## READING THE FILE CONTENT

**SOLUTION**
Use `URL` with `Scanner`.

**CODE**

```
URL url = new URL("http://filehost.blob.core.windows.net/firmware/version.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
while (s.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(s.nextLine());
s.close();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1.016
```

**NOTE**
 `MalformedURLException` and `IOException` must be `thrown` or handled.

## DOWNLOADING THE FILE

**SOLUTION**
Use [JAVA NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).

**CODE**

```
URL website = new URL("http://filehost.blob.core.windows.net/firmware/version.txt");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/version.txt");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

**OUTPUT**
 file has been created at `c:\test\version.txt` with 5 bytes size

**NOTE**
 `MalformedURLException`, `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` must be `thrown` or handled.

Comment: There are a lot of CAPITALS in that answer!!

Comment: There are 2 sollutions divided in parts... I used to clarify

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code snippet and could not reproduce your problem - it does not hang for me. I think that your network (configuration) may have some problems and that your code hangs until some timeout occurs.